# How to access a config file from a library installed in node_modules?

Tags: node.js

I published a nodejs library to `npm registry` which includes some configuration files e.g. `json, yml etc`. In this library, it needs to load these configuration files from local disk. But when this library is used by other nodejs project, these configuration files are located under `node_modules/module_name/xxx/*.yml`.

How can I specify the path in the library to load these configuration files?

```
const fs = require('fs');

let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('config/spec.yml');
```

In above code, it loads the file from `config/spec.yml` path. But if it is used by other module, do I have to change the path to be `'node_modules/xxxx/config/spec.yml'`?

Comment: You could provide an API in your module to get a path to the config files and your module can then build that full path based on `__dirname` or `import.meta.url` so the caller doesn't have to know the internal structure of your module.  After all, it's a resource that belongs to your module.  A caller should logically get access to it via an API.

Comment: what do you mean by `API in your module`?

Comment: A function you export from your module.,